# How to pass a struct as an argument in call using web3.py

Tags: web3.py, struct

Following is a working code on remix. It is recommended to use `memory` keyword for the `struct` parameter. Please also see: [Solidity Storage Array Bugs](https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/06/25/solidity-storage-array-bugs/).

Which does not work on `Web3.py` and gives the following error:

```
ValueError: No matching entries for 'tuple' in encoder registry
```

**[Q]** How could I fix this error?

---

Example code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;  
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
   
contract HelloWorld {
    struct User {
        string name;
        uint age;
    }
    
    User[] users;        
    function addUser(User memory user_) public  {
        users.push(user_);
    }
            
    function getUser(uint index) public view returns(User memory) {
        require(index >=0 && index < users.length);
        return users[index];
    }
}
```

---

```
user = ["hello", 10];
HelloWorld.transact().addUser(user);
```

Comment: What version of web3.py are you using? You might try with the v5 beta. tuples might not be supported in v4.

Comment: You will find solution in the following link. https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract.deploy

Answer (score 1):

I tested with `buildtransaction` and works well.

I'm using BSC Testnet in my example but it will work on another chain too.

## Initial configuration

You need to have some BNBs (ether) in your wallet to pay gas fees because you are changing the blockchain state.

```
from web3 import Web3

#== Setup RPC/Web3 ==#
rpc = "your rpc address"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(rpc))

#== Setup Wallet ==#
wallet = "your wallet address"
pk = "your wallet pk"

#== Setup CA and ABI ==#
contract_address = "put your ca here"
abi = [{"constant": "false","inputs": [{"components": [{"internalType": "string","name": "name","type": "string"},{"internalType": "uint256","name": "age","type": "uint256"}],"internalType": "struct HelloWorld.User","name": "user_","type": "tuple"}],"name": "addUser","outputs": [],"payable": "false","stateMutability": "nonpayable","type": "function"},{"constant": "true","inputs": [{"internalType": "uint256","name": "index","type": "uint256"}],"name": "getUser","outputs": [{"components": [{"internalType": "string","name": "name","type": "string"},{"internalType": "uint256","name": "age","type": "uint256"}],"internalType": "struct HelloWorld.User","name": "","type": "tuple"}],"payable": "false","stateMutability": "view","type": "function"}]

hw_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=abi)
```

## addUser function

Please change Gas and GasPrice if necessary.

```
def addUserTest(_newUser):
    adduser = hw_contract.functions.addUser(_newUser).buildTransaction({
        'from': wallet,
        'value': 0,
        'gas': 100000, #change here if necessary
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei(10,'gwei'), #change here if necessary
        'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(wallet),
    })
    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(adduser, private_key=pk)
    send_txn = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    txn_result = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(send_txn)  

    if txn_result['status'] == 1: 
        print("Success: ", web3.toHex(send_txn))     
    else: 
        print("Error: ", web3.toHex(send_txn))

addUserTest(["Kenji",20])
```

## getUser function

```
def getUserTest(_id):
    user = hw_contract.functions.getUser(_id).call()
    return user

print(getUserTest(0)) #use this after add a user or will get a revert message.
```

### **Output:**

Python:

[image: addUser getUser output]

---

Remix:

[image: addUser getUser output]

---